# How do I change the weekday language in the Gnome Shell clock?

Tags: language-support, clock

there is a funny thing happening to me in my computer. I have my Gnome Ubuntu 16.04 set to Spanish. In the top bar, I have date (with weekday) and clock. The thing is that weekday appears in German (I live in Germany, maybe because of my IP address) and I don't find the way to set it to default or Spanish.

[image: This is how my clock looks today]

Even funnier is that the rest of the date appears in Spanish. Only weekday makes a mess. Does anyone knows where to tweak this settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Region & Language*, change *Format* from German to Spanish, and relogin.

Comment: There was it! That solved my problem. Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: @nezah: Good. Then can you please click the gray check mark to the left to show others that it was solved.